# Compiling Java classes in linux via command line

Tags: java, compilation, junit4

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.

I have two files in my root folder (~/). The Main.Java and TestMain.java. Main.java compiles and runs smoothly. TestMain on the other hand does not. TestMain is basically a test class where I use JUnit to handle different scenarios. I instantiate Main in TestMain but the problem is that the compiler cannot find Main.java.

Here's the code:

```
    user@linuxbox ~ $ javac -cp junit-4.10.jar TestMain.java 
    TestMain.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                Main mainClass = new Main();
                ^
      symbol:   class Main
      location: class TestMain
    TestMain.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                Main luckyStrings = new Main();
                                                ^
      symbol:   class Main
      location: class TestMain
    2 errors
```

How can I make the Main class available to the MainTest.java class? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your classpath option, you have set the classpath to *only* `junit-4.10.jar`.  You must also include the current directory where your Java files reside.

```
javac -cp "junit-4.10.jar:." TestMain.java
```

This includes two paths -- JUnit and the current directory, separated by a `:`.  (If this were Windows, then you would use a `;` as a separator).

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks for your time and assistance. Will mark you answer the correct as soon as possible! One question though.. what difference did the quotes make?

Comment: I used quotes because I'm used to quoting things in the shell that could be interpreted as something special to the shell.  I don't believe that having quotes here makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just another input...

-d can be used to specify the target directory where the compiled class files should be put

```
javac -d . -cp "junit-4.10.jar:." TestMain.java
```